# Check if string contains pattern (with respect to one-to-one symbols mapping)

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, strings, hash, substrings

I'm trying to solve following problem:

> Check, if the *string* contains substring, that can be obtained from *pattern* using one to one lower case symbols replacement (using bijection between original lower case letters and new letters).

My strings **only consist of upper case and lower case english alphabet letters (*A–Z, a–z*)** .

For example:

> ***Positive***:
> string: ***justanexampleXstring***
> pattern: ***onecompleX***
> answer: ***true** (anexampleX <-> onecompleX, used mapping: a<->o, x<->c; uppercase is not affected by mapping)*
> ***Negative:***
> string: ***AaBbDd***
> pattern: ***AaBa***
> answer: ***false*** (two repeated lower case letters in pattern and no repeated lower case letters in original string)

Currently I'm thinking about utilizing [Rabin–Karp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) algorithm in [multiple pattern search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm#Multiple_pattern_search) setup:

> A naïve way to search for k patterns is to repeat a single-pattern search taking O(n+m) time, totaling in O((n+m)k) time. In contrast, the above algorithm can find all k patterns in O(n+km) expected time, assuming that a hash table check works in O(1) expected time.

But naïve check of strings generated by all possible mappings leads to k=**26!** (*factorial*, number of all possible one to one mappings between 26 letters alphabet)

Any ideas or optimizations to current approach would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You dont need to check all $k!$ bijections, simply because if you are trying to match a particular substring to the pattern - the bijection is constructed by mapping the $i$'th letter in the substring to the $i$'th letter in the pattern. Then, you only have to check that this is indeed a bijection: if it is, accept this as a correct substring, and otherwise continue to search.

Comment: Cross-posted from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69814994/check-if-string-contains-pattern-with-respect-to-one-to-one-symbols-mapping), where it has an accepted answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).